# Why isn't JavaScript throwing exceptions as the result of an asynchronous HTTP (AJAX) request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, exception

I've written the following JavaScript function which is very simple, it takes an ID and which then is sent to a PHP page, which echoes out some JSON. It passes the ID into the PHP page via GET.

For example, if I was to make the following GET request: `/processing/getAccountInfo.php?id=5`, it would return this (got from a database): `{"username":"carefulnow","profileImg":null}`. This is correct, so I know my PHP is working fine.

My JavaScript code that originally called the AJAX now needs to process it, echo it out and check it for errors. If the PHP function encounters any errors, the returned JSON will contain an "errorMsg" which contains the name of the PHP exception that it encountered including a specific message (`Exception::getMessage()`). An example error result would be `{"errorMsg":"PDOException: some error..."}`.

```
function getAccountInfo(id) {

    var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    var inner = document.getElementById("accInfInner");

    var name = document.getElementById("accInfName");
    var img = document.getElementById("accInfImg");

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

            try {
                var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                if (response.errorMsg === undefined) {

                    if (response.username === undefined || response.profileImg === undefined) {
                        throw new Error("Could not get the username and profile image. Try logging in then back out.");
                    }

                    name.innerHTML = response.username;

                    // The profile image is not required.

                    if (response.profileImg !== null) {
                        img.src = response.profileImg;
                    } else {
                        img.src = "/assets/img/defaultuser.jpg";
                    }

                    loading.style.display = "none";
                    inner.style.display = "block";

                } else {
                    throw new Error(response.errorMsg);
                }
            } catch (exception) {
                inner.innerHTML = "Error. Hover for details.";
                inner.title = exception.message;
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/processing/getAccountInfo.php?id=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

The problem, however, is that the throw statements aren't working. If an error is thrown from the PHP, nothing happens (no errors in the console)! My IDE (PHPStorm 2017.1) gives the following error: "'throw' of exception caught locally", which after a *lot* of searching, I cannot find anyone else having this same issue. Is it something to do with the GET request been asynchronous, or is it something a lot simpler I'm not seeing?

Comment: Is your PHP call returning a 200 result in the event of an error?

Comment: What is the HTTP response code sent from server if your PHP function encounters an error?

Comment: 200. The error is reported via the JSON result been set to "errorMsg", which contains the appropriate error message to report. Here's my PHP function: https://pastebin.com/raw/uLr0WLBa

Comment: So you can see the `GET` request completes successfully from the browser (_in the network tab of browser's console_)?

Comment: Yep. http://i.imgur.com/wiIhGvA.png. Also, if I do `alert(this.status);` after the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function, it shows as 200. The PHP is certainly responding successfully.

Comment: Didn't see a `GET` request for `/processing/getAccountInfo.php?id=` in screenshot

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. For some reason the Firefox one isn't showing it, but the Chrome inspector does: http://i.imgur.com/3tUvBII.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145732/discussion-between-pete-and-carefulnow).